# Pop to root view when tab is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've been having some trouble with something I thought might be easy. I have a table in my root view controller, when a row is selected I push a new view and from there I go to another tab.

My question is how do I make sure that as soon as the user taps the first tab the navigation controller will pop to root?

Answer (score 28):

Following delegate is called while each tab is selected on tabbar.

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Put following code inside this delegate method.

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) 
    {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

its working fine on my app.

Comment: Really very helpful for me, working fine in my app according to my requirement.

Comment: What file is the delegate? I tried creating a UINavigationController and specifying it as the delegate. I see its called on viewDidLoad but specifying it as the delegate for UITabBarDelegate or UITabBarControllerDelegate doesn't call this method.

Comment: I am bit confused.Can you tell me where I add this code

Comment: For those who can't make this doesn't work, try adding `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the header file (.h), and `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;` in the implementation file (.m).

Answer (score 11):

For Swift lovers:

```
import UIKit

class YourTabBarControllerHere: UITabBarController,
UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
            if let vc = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                vc.popViewControllerAnimated(animated: false);
            }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Swift 3 update, thanks to @Justin Oroz for pointing that out.

Comment: As OP's question asked for ROOT controller, it should be (in Swift 3 syntax)
`vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3.1

Add UITabBarControllerDelegate to your TabBar Class:

> class YourClass: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

After:

> override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item:
>   UITabBarItem) {
>
> ```
> let yourView = self.viewControllers![self.selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
> yourView .popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do sounds a little bit odd. Have you read the Human Interface Guidelines on combining UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers?

However, what you need to do is detect the selection of the tab by setting a delegate for your UITabBarController and implementing the tabBarController:didSelectViewController: delegate method. In this method you need to pop back to the root view controller using UINavigationController's popToRootViewControllerAnimated: method.

Comment: If you check out Apple's Phone.app the favorites and recent tab's behavior is the same as what the OP wants.

Comment: The Phone app does not switch tabs when you select a table row - this was the behaviour I was querying, not popping to root when the user taps a different tab.

Comment: Ah, yes the OP's question is not entirely what OP means by "from there I go to another tab". Does the user select another tab or does the app switch automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.1 Answer:

```
  class YourTabBarName: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate
    {

     override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.delegate = self
        }


     func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
        {
            if let vc = viewController as? UINavigationController
            { vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Changing animated to NO actually helped me. When I had animated set to YES, my tab bar nor any other buttons in navigation controller were not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

The solution that works for me is to subclass the UITabBarController and add the two delegate functions as follows:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var previousSelectedTabIndex:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.previousSelectedTabIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
}


override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item:
    UITabBarItem) {
    let vc = self.viewControllers![previousSelectedTabIndex] as! UINavigationController
    vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

}

}
```

Make sure you set animated to false otherwise you will get

```
 Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for the targeted ViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class TabBarClass: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        let vc = self.viewControllers![selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
        vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create subclass of UITabbarController and add Observer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tabBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}
```

When tabbar is selected, We will process in method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectedItem"] && [object isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]){
        UITabBar *bar = (UITabBar *)object; // The object will be the bar we're observing.
        // The change dictionary will contain the previous tabBarItem for the "old" key.
        UITabBarItem *wasItem = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
        NSUInteger was = [bar.items indexOfObject:wasItem];
        // The same is true for the new tabBarItem but it will be under the "new" key.
        UITabBarItem *isItem = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        NSUInteger is = [bar.items indexOfObject:isItem];
        if (is == was) {
           UIViewController *vc = self.viewControllers[is];
            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                [(UINavigationController *)vc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UTabController suggests a different UX for letting a user "pop to root". When switching back to a tab, it keeps the full UINav stack from before. If they tap the bar item a second time (tapping the selected tab), only then does it pop to root. That's all automatic. Some apps, like instagram, allow a third tap to scroll to top.

I'd suggest sticking with the defaults as that's what users will be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The below had worked for me .This code in swift 3:

1> subclass UITabbarController  and  implement two below method  with one iVAr:
    `class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController ,UITabBarControllerDelegate {
var previousSelectedTabIndex : Int = -1 
}`

2> set the tabbar delegate in viewdidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self    // you must do it}  

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    self.previousSelectedTabIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
}     
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                               shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {    

    if  self.previousSelectedTabIndex == tabBarController.selectedIndex {
        let   nav  =  viewController as! UINavigationController // mine in nav_VC
        for vc in nav.childViewControllers {
            if vc is YUOR_DESIRED_VIEW_CONTROLLER {
            nav.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return false// IT WONT LET YOU GO TO delegate METHOD
            }
        }
    }
 return true
}
```

tabBarController.selectedIndex give you the selected tab

In tabBarController_shouldSelect_viewController method you can set your desired view controller  with some easy calculation.
if you are not getting the above code play with  both above method and you come to know how  both working together

Comment: This approach logs Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for the targeted ViewController even though it does work.
I am trying to find a solution that will not log the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use selected view controller to popToRootViewController. Basically you need to cast this instance.

**Swift**

```
((selectedViewController) as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: false)
//
// I just added extra line so the scroll bar won't annoy you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11.5, Swift 5:

You don't need to use two delegate methods. Only one is enough:

```
extension CustomTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController) == tabBarController.selectedIndex,
            let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a tabbar controller class set it to your TabbarController in storyboard
import UIKit

class MyTabbarViewController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
 
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        if let vc = viewController as? UINavigationController
        { vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false) }
    }

  

}
```