# Get back to root view when tab is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

With reference to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650700/pop-to-root-view-when-tab-is-selected) I added `UITabDelegate` and `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in `AppDelegate.h` and added

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

in `AppDelegate.m`. Still the issue is not solved. I am using XIB in my project and handling login and logout to enable and disable tab bar accordingly.

Comment: I believe viewController in that method will be navigation controller root view controller not uinavigationcontroller directly.

Comment: I am using tab bar with navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this:

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ClassName_Of_Selected_ViewController class]])
    {
        //[(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
} is not working

Comment: did you used UINavigationController in your app. And don't compare with [UINavigationController class]. Compare with the name of UIViewController class.

Comment: I compared it with UIViewController class. Didn't work.

Comment: What is the name of you class? And did you used `UINavigationController` in your app? if you used the only `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` will work.

Comment: Obviously I used navigationController in my class. I navigated to 2nd view within one tab. When I tap on the tab, I need it to be on the 1st view.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I updated my answer for how to compare it. You need to write the name of your class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43052/discussion-between-optimus-prime-and-bhumeshwer-katre)