# TabBar shouldSelectViewController Issues

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm using the tab bar controller template that is packaged with swift. I have embedded the FirstViewController and SecondViewController into a navigation controller. I have added a third ViewController that is accessed by a segue from the FirstViewController. When I'm in the third ViewController and I hit the SecondViewController tab the simulator takes me to the SecondViewController but when I hit the FirstViewController tab, I'm taken back to the third ViewController - I want to go back to the FirstViewController when I select it's tab. What is the way to implement this? Searching through the documentation I think I should be using:

```
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
     shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pop to root view when tab is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650700/pop-to-root-view-when-tab-is-selected). This answer seems relevant.

Swift code:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
   if let viewController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
      viewController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it could work though I think I would have to create my own subclass of UITabBarController so I could set the delegate. When using the XCode template how do you know how to set the delegate?

Comment: Yes, you would have to subclass UITabBarController and implement the delegate method. When you subclass UITabBarController, XCode will allow you to implement delegate methods automatically because it assumes you want to control the UITabBarDelegate. All you have to do is go to your TabBarController in story board. Click the Tab Bar, go to Outlets, and drag the circle next to delegate to the TabBarController. Now go to your TabBarController, go to Custom Class, and set the Class to the subclass you made.

Answer (score 0):

For newer Versions of Swift the delegate function should be as following:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if let viewController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        viewController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }
}
```

Your class has to be consistent with the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and the delegate property should be set during the loading process.