# Tabbar controller showing last pushed controller - swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar controller with 3 tabs(all view controllers are embedded in navigation controller) while clicking the 3rd tab am showing a view controller with start button, clicking start it goes to the next controller, from this controller by programmatically am pushing to another vc. Now my issue is when I click the 3rd tab it showing the last pushed controller instead of showing a view controller with start button.

If I double click the 3rd tab it showing the current view controller.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650700/pop-to-root-view-when-tab-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

That’s how it is supposed to work, if you want to show the root vc for tab 3 you’ll need to call popToRootViewController() on the navigationController.

```
aVC.navigationController.popToRootViewController()
```

You would need to call the above when the relevant tab button is tapped, so you can use UITabBarControllerDelegate to find out when that happens.

Comment: on the navigation controller mean?

Comment: Am calling it inside the delegate method   override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {    if tabBar.items?.index(of: item) == 5{
     let jjForm = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JJController")
        jjForm?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)          
        }}

Comment: UITabBarControllerDelegate not UITabBarDelegate. Check if selected VC is 3rd VC in tbc.viewControllers and if so you can call popToRoot...()

Comment: Also you’re creating a new instance of the VC in your code, you need to access the existing VC that is held by the TabBarController